# Stop / Cancel ingestion into Azure Data Explorer (LightIngest)

Tags: azure-data-explorer

Is there a way to cancel / stop a running ingestion started by LightIngest. We ingested some files (local disk) and realized too late that the pattern was wrong. We couldn't find any documentation on how to stop a started ingestion other than waiting till its done.

Any ideas or links to documentation (that we haven't found)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

in-flight queued ingestions are currently non-cancellable.

assuming this is the only source of ingestions into the table, and you don't care about existing data in the table - you could try to drop the table, and have all of those fail permanently, then re-create the table.

you could also submit/upvote a feature request @ https://aka.ms/adx.uservoice

Comment: Thanks. For the record, there was a feature request already: https://feedback.azure.com/forums/915733-azure-data-explorer/suggestions/40649548-cancelling-in-flight-queued-ingestions